# How to separate javascript code for different parts of the site?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two conceptual parts of the site - public, which is shown to users when they are guests.

I want public part to be as lightweight in the JS code as possible, rendering many elements on the server and passing them as HTML, then doing some stuff with client JS code.

The user part of the site is when user logs in and it's more dynamic in its structure, can be quite large in its JS code size. User manages her content here, add, remove, search and filter. It's fine to wait some more time while this part is loading.

I suppose, I want to make codebase separate for public and private parts of the site but I still want to not duplicate code if possible, between two.

I see these ways:
1. Use a small JS file which figures out where it's located and then loads the main logic file depending on the current context - private or public.
2. Completely separate logic and put into 2 independent files, then attach to 2 respective html templates.
3. Have a file with logic for public part, and if it happens that user logs in, dynamically load private logic file from the public file.

How do I decide what way is the best one? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your 3rd approach would work the best.
1st brings latency coming from intermediate step for determining user current privileges. 2nd require full page reload. 3rd seems most reasonable if done right.

If you set a cookie to remember that user is logged in for the next visit you could possibly attach both scripts on server (if your HTML is generated dynamically) or even have them merged together for sending as one file when needed. If using some build tools like gulp or grunt this could be easy to maintain.